# case statement with expression throws error

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am trying to execute below statement in Oracle, but it throws error. Kindly help.

```
select a.PHONE_NUMBER, 
CASE a.PHONE_NUMBER
WHEN '2262070200' THEN '2262070200'
WHEN a.PHONE_NUMBER = '2262070201' OR a.PHONE_NUMBER = '2262070202' THEN '2ND'
END
from temp_a a;
```

Error :

> ORA-00905: missing keyword

Data in Temp_a

```
2262070200
2262070201
2262070202
2262070203
2262070204
2262070205
2262070206
2262070223
2262070224
2262070225
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be like this

```
select a.PHONE_NUMBER, 
CASE 
WHEN a.PHONE_NUMBER = '2262070200' THEN '2262070200'
WHEN a.PHONE_NUMBER = '2262070201' OR a.PHONE_NUMBER = '2262070202' THEN '2ND'
END
from temp_a a;
```

Comment: Case supports both syntax, **simple** and **searched**.

Comment: Yes Lalit I know that, but for his case it should be this way

Comment: Yes, due to multiple conditions in same WHEN clause. Anyway, I have marked the topic as duplicate as similar question has been asked before.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error

Statement should be

```
select a.PHONE_NUMBER,
CASE 
WHEN a.PHONE_NUMBER ='2262070200' 
 THEN '2262070200' 
WHEN a.PHONE_NUMBER = '2262070201' OR a.PHONE_NUMBER = '2262070202' 
 THEN '2ND' 
END 
from temp_a a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.PHONE_NUMBER,
  CASE 
    WHEN a.PHONE_NUMBER = '2262070200'
    THEN '2262070200'
    WHEN a.PHONE_NUMBER = '2262070201'  OR a.PHONE_NUMBER   = '2262070202'
    THEN '2ND'
  END
FROM temp_a a;
```